# Declare sources files private inside project CMake

Tags: c, cmake

There are 2 functions with same name on different subprojects. I am looking for solution in CMake that they won't be linked at main_project and thus resulting in erorr:

> multiple definition of

Simplified main project CMakeLists

```
project(main_project)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} PRIVATE
A1
A2
)
```

Example subproject

```
project(A1)

add_library(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
api.c
internal1.c
internal2.c
internal3.c)
```

Let's say funtion fun1 is inside each project A1 and A2 internal1.c source file.

I toyed a bit with `_VISIBILITY_PRESET` but with no success there

Comment: If you have access to the source code, why don't you just refactor the problematic function in one, or both sub projects with the help of the IDE?

Comment: I could just rename it but it's: not a solution, happens multiple times

Comment: I suppose, that there are many functions which should be visible across projects. cmake won't be able to tell which should be exclusive to just one project, so you will need to deal with each function individual anyhow. I don't think that telling cmake (somehow) one-by-one that those function should be renamed (made "private") would be less effort then refactoring them one-by-one with the IDE.

Comment: If there are many inner functions, and only a few which should be visible across projects, you could just refactor all functions with a tool (adding something to the beginning of the names) and then go one-by-one on the rest to restore the original names.

Comment: Aren't there any other way? I may not emphasis this enough but those duplicate are used only inside subproject and somehow hiding them from main project should do the job.

Comment: Using shared libraries instead of static ones, and playing with the function visibility, may help.